# Using .ToString on a Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I do a link who have a value on the where that I have to transform into a string 
Like this example:

```
 Fund.ObjectName = context.CR_TASK.First(a => Convert.ToString(a.TASK_NO) == item.DATA_TEXT).TASK_TITLE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `FirstOrDefault` to assign null if no item matches:

```
Fund.ObjectName = context.CR_TASK
    .Where(a => a.TASK_NO.ToString() == item.DATA_TEXT)
    .Select(a => a.TASK_TITLE)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```